# ViewChild reference of searchBar suddenly undefined when moving to child component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good afternoon!
I implemented a searchbar like described in https://www.chriswoolum.dev/using-ion-searchbar-to-filter-an-observable-collection for my Angular + Ionic app.

After moving it to a own component, suddenly the searchBar is undefined, even in the ngAfterViewInit() where it should have been initialized already.

my-list.component.ts

```
  @ViewChild(IonSearchbar, {static: true}) searchBar: IonSearchbar;
  @ViewChild(IonSelect, {static: true}) selectBodypart: IonSelect;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.searchBar) # undefined
  }
```

my-list.component.html

```
  <ion-searchbar #searchBar placeholder="Search.."></ion-searchbar>
```

Does anyone have an idea or can explain to me how the lifecycle is for component as somehow it is handled differently than directly using it in a page.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you find a solution to get the component instance at the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@ViewChild()` with `{static : true}` it basically means you expect that component to be present as soon as the page loads, therefore the `@Viewchild()` query will not update on every digest cycle.

In simple terms, this means that **if your component is displayed based on an ngIf, `{static : true}` will not pick it up**.

For the sake of the argument i'm gonna assume your

```
<ion-searchbar #searchBar placeholder="Search.."></ion-searchbar>
```

Is wrapped by an *ngIf at a higher level

Try to change your code with

```
@ViewChild(IonSearchbar, {static: false}) searchBar: IonSearchbar;
@ViewChild(IonSelect, {static: false}) selectBodypart: IonSelect;
```

you should then see your component

If that also does not work try to reference your component directly like so:

```
@ViewChild("searchBar", {static: false}) searchBar: IonSearchbar;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

The searchBar is not wrapped into an *ngIf on any level. Furthermore, the 'static: false' does not seem to make any difference.

When I use the direct reference using "searchBar" I get a reference, but the previously working this.searchBar.ionChange.pipe(... still is not working, namely TypeError: undefined is not an object ... so maybe I am getting a reference but not on the intended object of the child component? 
This is really strange behaviour IMO. Maybe you have some further thoughts on this? :)